# Proper method to make a class of other class instances

Tags: python, pandas

I'm working on building a simple report generator that will run a query, put the data into a formatted excel sheet and email it.

I am trying to get better at proper coding practices (cohesion, coupling, etc) and I am wondering if this is the proper way to build this or if there's a better way. It feels somewhat redundant to have to pass the arguments of the `Extractor` twice: once to the main class and then again to the subclass.

Should I be using nested classes? `**kwargs`? Or is this correct?

```
from typing_extensions import ParamSpec
import pandas as pd
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from O365 import Account
from jinjasql import JinjaSql

class Emailer:
    pass

class Extractor:
    '''Executes a sql query and returns the data.'''
    
    def __init__(self, query: str, database: str, connection: dict, param_query: bool = False) -> None:
        self.query = query
        self.database = database

        # self.conn_params = connection

        self.engine = create_engine(connection)

        # self.engine = Reactor().get_engine(**self.conn_params)

    def parse_query(self) -> None:
        '''If the query needs parameterization, do that here.'''
        pass

    def run_query(self) -> None:
        '''Run a supplied query. Expects the name of the query.'''

        # TODO: Make this check if it's a query or a query name.
        with open(self.query, "r") as f:
            query = f.read()

        return pd.read_sql_query(query, self.engine)
        

class ReportGenerator:
    '''Main class'''

    def __init__(self, query: str, connection: dict, param_query: bool = False) -> None:

        self.extractor = Extractor(query, connection, param_query)
        self.emailer = Emailer()

    def build_report(self) -> None:
        pass
```

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a bad solution, but I think it can be improved.

If you'll continue this correctly, ReportGenerator should never know about query/connection and other members of Extractor, thus it shouldn't be passed to his constructor.
What you can do instead is create an Extractor and an Emailer before the creation of the ReportGenerator and pass them to the constructor.